# Is there a way to append files efficiently using the DOS copy command?

Tags: file-transfer, ms-dos, disk-operating-system, freedos

Using the DOS copy command syntax to concatenate files:

```
copy file1.txt+file2.txt all.txt
```

I know I can do this...

```
copy file1.txt+file2.txt file1.txt
```

Is this efficient?  Is it doing what I'm expecting?  It works, but I want to know is it actually appending to file1.txt or is it copying file1.txt (bad), concatenating file2 and then renaming to file1.txt (which is not efficient)?

Comment: As a side note, remember that you need to use the "/b" switch if you ever decide to use copy to cat binary files.

Comment: Nobody here seems to think that the case of "huge files" is worth addressing, or giving a solution to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`copy` is copying `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` into memory, concatenating them then writing out to `file1.txt`. It's not copying to a new file then renaming that file so really there's not much extra disk I/O.

You can also use `type`.

```
type file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

The `>>` operator appends text. But that will, of course, not work for binary files.

Comment: it should work fine for binary files.  it's just not generally useful, because most binary data formats use some form of encapsulation such that even in the combined file, only the first file will be recognized & used.  if you had, say, 2 raw PCM files, this would be a fine way to concatenate them (as opposed to 2 WAV files, where another program is needed to alter headers).

Comment: I was using the term renaming very loosely.  If file1 and file2 are huge files I want file2 appended to file1 WITHOUT copying any file1 data (it is too big to copy again).  Tyler, you have suggested it will copy file1.txt data.  Using the type command, this will actually append?  Thanks.

Comment: Be warned, though that old DOS versions failed to copy a target to the target with copy source+otherfile source. It resulted in a 64 kB source file because a 64 kB buffer was used for reading and writing, and after the first flush, the source was just 64 kB :-) no joke.

Comment: *> copy is copying … into memory, concatenating them then writing out to file1.txt. It's not copying to a new file then renaming that file so really there's not much extra disk I/O.*   That might be true for tiny files, but definitely not true for files of any significant size. What if the two files are huge? Do a test and you will notice that memory usage does **not** go up during the redirection. Therefore it is not combining them in memory. And of course it cannot combine them two the original file since it has not finished reading it, so it *is* using a temporary file/pipe.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this efficient?

Sure. However, using the the `/b` switch can/may increase performance by simply concatenating the bytes instead of processing the files as text. This is particularly noticeable when concatenating very large text files.

> Is it doing what I'm expecting?

Usually yes, but if the file was made in Linux, Mac, or other system with differing file-/line-terminators, then it may give unexpected results. It is a good idea to use the `/b` switch in general, even for text files.

> I want to know is it actually appending to file1.txt or is it copying file1.txt (bad), concatenating file2 and then renaming to file1.txt (which is not efficient)?

Yes, it is creating a new, temporary file, deleting the original, and renaming the temp file to the original name, but deleting and renaming take no time and unless the original file is massive, you won’t normally notice even the (redundant) copying of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

If they are of the same extension you could do this -

type `*.txt >> fileout.tmp`.

Then rename `fileout.tmp` to the proper extension.

Answer (score 0):

Find base directory where files are located

0. `dir /b /s *.xml > dirlist.txt`
1. edit each line of `dirlist.txt` using copy+replace, i.e.-
2. `l:\dir1\dir2\file.xml`
3. replace `l:\` with `" m:\dest.txt&lt;br>copy /b m:\dest.txt+"`
4. save file as `dirlist.htm`
5. open file in browser
6. copy the results back to editor
7. fix the first and last lines
8. save the file as `.bat`
9. open command prompt and run the `.bat` file

Results of binary copy appended to `m:\dest.txt`

*Note: I do recall that old MS-DOS would internally hack up files with the same source and destinations (64k). For very large file products it would be <strike>better</strike> safer to use a temp file. If the OS can't handle the task using a temp file due to internal buffer limits or poor coding, the DOS will fail the task.

*Note: For any appended target file approaching 1 GB, I would suggest copying all of the target files to a temp directory and committing `copy /b *.*; target.file`.

Answer (score 0):

Files are streams--meaning they really work like a tape deck that you can instantly move anywhere, but you still have to "press play" and consume data serially.  So you can do the following:

- Move a seek pointer somewhere between 0 and the end of the file.
- Read where the seek pointer is, moving the seek pointer forward.
- Write where the seek pointer is, moving the seek pointer forward.  If you keep going past the end of the file you are making the file bigger.

That's it.  Well, one more thing:

- Tell the OS that the seek pointer is the new end of the file.  This is a truncate and everything after the end is lost.

If you want to "delete" something in the middle or beginning of the file, you've got to rewrite the whole file - starting from the end and moving to the beginning.

So one thing that traditional files do not do well is shrink from the beginning.

So, it's hard to do an "efficient" append that shrinks the 2nd source file while stitching on the first.

It's definitely *possible* but you'd have to manipulate filesystem structures to do it in a way that would be worth it timewise - the filesystem strctures are the OS and filesystem-specific stuff you don't see with *dir* and File Exmplorer.  That means each filesystem in existence--NTFS, FAT32, ext2 (Linux)--would need its own method of doing this.

I'm not aware of any Windows "stitching" utilities that exist that allow you to combine files without having space for a third file.  There may be some out there, if you do find any, be *very wary* and test *thoroughly* as it's basically manipulating files in a nonstandard unsafe way and if the utility doesn't work 100% as advertised, you will lose data!